# text-align is working only for text

Tags: css, text-align

I'm sitting like 2 hours opposite of this, tried housands of ways with firebug and I lost my patience...

I got an table , inside of it I got text message, and `text-align: center;` is working great for it, the problem appear when I need to center my `markItUp!` textarea editor.

There is no way to force it to be centered, I've tried adding `!important` attribute, and still the same.

Have you guys know any way, to 'force' the `div` to be centered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the div a width and set its left and right margins to auto.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5xc0rjJ8 Got this, and `<textarea>` is still at the left position.

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` and give the div a `width`.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5wzeP/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5xc0rjJ8 Got this, and `<textarea>` is still at the left position.